# What are some good applications for creating lecture-like videos?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, video-recording, desktop-recording

I want to make videos like the ones in [this YouTube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZXCq2fn-Z0&list=PL8DC1113ADB63358E&index=1).

Where I can write stuff and talk about stuff at the same time.

My first instinct was to shop around for a pen-tablet I can use to do the writing, but then I realized I didn't know what kind of software I would need to make "pen-tablet videos" and whether such software would be compatible with the specific pen-tablet I would buy.

So those of you who know how this could be done on Ubuntu, what are the (software and compatible hardware) tools I would need to make videos like that?

Comment: Screen caster/recorder in addition to a hardware based canvas or a single canvas plus a hardware like Bamboo Wacom Tablet (I use the MTE-450) seems to  be in use in the video link you provided. Check the list of screencasting software that  other users are dropping as answers and make sure you gather the proper writing hardware. You won't be able to emulate such behavior with mouse. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

**Vokoscreen: A new screen casting tool for Linux**

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vokoscreen-dev/vokoscreen
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install vokoscreen
```

[image]

[**For More HELP**](http://www.unixmen.com/vokoscreen-a-new-screencasting-tool-for-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

Another application which is often used is Kazam, which you can find [here](https://launchpad.net/kazam). You can find the application called "kazam" in the standard repositories, but you can also add their ppa via this command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kazam-team/stable-series
```

Until recently though you would get a more functional programme when you added the unstable repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:kazam-team/unstable-series
```

This programme as well as vokoscreen mentiond above just records your desktop. It is important that you know if your tablet is compatible with the kernel you use. I have no experience with this hardware, so unfortunately I am not able to help you further with this.

Answer (score -1):

Istanbul Desktop Seasson Recorder is a good on of good screen capture

download it from [here](http://zaheer.merali.org/istanbul-0.2.2.tar.bz2)